# Deleted photos still using storage?

Tags: storage, photos, nokia-lumia-1020

My phone was running low on storage after a few months of snapping photos using the JPG + RAW option in the Lumia 1020. I used the Windows Phone tool for OS X to backup all the files to my Mac, and then used it to delete the photos from the phone.

They no longer show up in the photo album on the phone, or in the desktop tool on my Mac, but the when I use the check storage facility on the phone it's still pretty much where it was before I deleted them, and I'm stuck with only around 2GB free. Any ideas on how to reclaim the lost storage space?

Comment: Are you sure you actually deleted both of the file sizes (high res and low res photos)? This sounds like you have transferred but not deleted them (not sure how the util works on a Mac)

Comment: I transferred and then deleted from within the Windows Phone Mac app. They no longer show in the Camera Roll on device or when browsing in the app. I'd kill for full file system access!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After upgrading to Windows Phone 8.1 I noticed the storage usage had moved to "Other" from photos. Turns out the Mac app for windows can't display or *delete* DNG files even though it can import them. The phone also doesn't show DNG files in the camera roll if the associated JPG files have been removed.

Plugging the phone into a Windows 8 machine, and browsing the file system via Explorer, I was able to see and then delete the DNG files which were all in the Photos directory as expected.

Answer (score 0):

> **"Other" phone storage**

The Nokia Pro Cam and Nokia Smart Cam apps save several files in addition to the photo you see in your phone's Camera Roll, and these are counted in "other". This includes for e.g. high-resolution photos taken by the Lumia 1020.

You can delete these from your phone from the Photos Hub, since you did that then you can connect your phone to your computer to delete or move them off your phone. The data for photo series created using burst mode are categorized as "other" as well.

Here is the [FAQ](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/how-to/wp8/settings-and-personalization/other-phone-storage-faq). Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't have a category for "Other"... I have temporary files which are only around 250MB. My issue is that photos are still showing as 15GB even though there are barely any on the phone.